Algebraic Topology: Deformation Retraction and Quotient Spaces (using Mobius )
Could someone please help me with this question (and its solution)? Thanks!!

Solution Part 1 (which shows that [0,1] x {1/2} deformation retract of [0,1] x [0,1]):


I don't get how the homotopy gets carried over to the quotient spaces. Like why does this work?
This is what I have tried doing (universal property of quotient maps: Munkres's Thm 22.2)

